# Replace entire input string using substr_replace?

Tags: php, string, replace, substr, strpos

**Example:** (***UPDATED*** - corrected the code below)

```
<?php

$canonical = 'http://eg.com/in/sample-post/';

$pos = strpos( $canonical, 'in' );

echo substr_replace( $canonical, 'main', $pos, strlen('in') );

// OUTPUT: http://eg.com/mamain/sample-post/

?>
```

As shown in the example, I am trying to replace the first instance of `uk` (subject) in the URL with `main` (replacement). Instead the output shows `mamain`. I am not sure why.

But the same code seems to work if the no. of characters in the *subject* is greater than *replacement*, e.g.

```
<?php

$canonical = 'http://eg.com/main/sample-post/';

$pos = strpos( $canonical, 'main' );

echo substr_replace( $canonical, 'uk', $pos, strlen('main') );

// OUTPUT: http://eg.com/uk/sample-post/

?>
```

Clearly, the second code although the same, does what I intend it to do.

How do I modify the code so that it works in both instances? What logic am I missing here?

**NOTE:**

- The code is only to give you an idea of what I am doing.
- I'd like to avoid having to use `preg_replace` to avoid regex complications.

Comment: The first example is working fine for me, I get the output `http://eg.com/main/sample-post/` as intended. Are you sure that there is no other error in your original code?

Comment: @BluePsyduck You are right. Corrected the code. You should be able to reproduce the error now.

Comment: Nope, I still get the same output. But now it looks like you are calling the function holding this code twice, so you replace the `in` to `main`, and then (by accident) again the `in` in `main` to `mamain`. Can you ensure that this code is only executed once on your variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your examples are working fine for me.

But it looks like you are calling the function holding this code twice, so you replace the `in` to `main`, and then (by accident) again the `in` in `main` to `mamain`.

Can you ensure that this code is only executed once on your variable?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preg_replace` here:

```
$canonical = 'http://eg.com/uk/sample-post/';
echo preg_replace('/\buk\b/', 'main', $canonical) . "\n";

$canonical = 'http://eg.com/main/sample-post/';
echo preg_replace('/\bmain\b/', 'uk', $canonical) . "\n";
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
http://eg.com/main/sample-post/
http://eg.com/uk/sample-post/
```

Comment: The reason why I am using `substr_replace` is to avoid the regex complications that come with `preg_replace`. :-/

Comment: Solutions should be driven by requirement. You requirement is such that a simple `preg_replace` can solve it without much complication.

Comment: The code shown in my question is only a sample of what I am doing (which is more dynamic). But thanks for your time. :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work for me:

```
$string = 'http://eg.com/uk/sample-post/';

echo substr_replace( $string, 'main', strpos($string,'uk'), strlen('uk'));
```

You could also use:

```
$string = 'http://eg.com/uk/sample-post/';

echo str_replace('uk','main', $string);
```

But this will replace all occurrences...

Comment: Jason, I had edited my question just before you posted your answer. Please take a look at the updated code (first code block) in my question.